# Excel Solver in R with 1 parameter

Tags: r, optimization, solver

I want to find and optimal K parameter for ELO calculation in a dataset.
My example:

```
#load SciViews for ln function
library("SciViews")

ELO1 <- c(1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 
                              1500.000, 1500.000, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1475.898, 1500.000, 1475.000, 1486.617, 1512.516)
ELO2 <- c(1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1499.550, 1500.450, 1499.550, 1512.950, 1487.050, 1512.950, 1524.102, 1500.000)
dataset <- data.frame("ELO1" = ELO1, "ELO2" = ELO2)
#Lets set if the Player1 was the winner:
dataset$HomeWinner <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
```

The winning probability for Player 1 according to ELO is calculated the following way:

```
dataset$P1ExpWin <- 1/(1 + 10^((dataset$ELO2 - dataset$ELO1)/400))
dataset$P2ExpWin <- 1 - dataset$P1ExpWin
```

Log error is calculated the following way:

```
dataset$LogError <- dataset$HomeWinner * ln(dataset$P1ExpWin) + (1-dataset$HomeWinner) * ln(1-dataset$P1ExpWin)
```

The K parameter sets the rate of ELO change and could vary between 4 and 32. Lets set it to 20:

```
Kparameter = 20
```

And the ELO change is calculated this way depending on the outcome:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(dataset)) {
    if (dataset[row,"HomeWinner"] == 1) {
      dataset$NewELO1[row] <- dataset$ELO1 + Kparameter * (1 - dataset$P1ExpWin)
      dataset$NewELO2[row] <- dataset$ELO2 - Kparameter * dataset$P2ExpWin
    }
    else{
      dataset$NewELO1[row] <- dataset$ELO1[row] - Kparameter * dataset$P1ExpWin
      dataset$NewELO2[row] <- dataset$ELO2[row] + Kparameter * (1 - dataset$P2ExpWin)
    }
}
```

Finally, log loss is calculated as a sum for every LogError, divided by the count:

```
LogLossELO = sum(dataset$LogError) * -1/nrow(dataset)
```

**My question is how to use optim or optimize function fo Kparameter to find the minimal LogLossELO (Similar to Solver in Excel)?**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am struggling to define a function because there are many equations.

Comment: Have moved comment to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed some of the formulas which did not make sense but this may or may not be what you intended.  Please review this and correct it if necessary.  Note that `ln` in SciViews is identical to `log` in base R so we replaced that too.  The `for` loop could be vectorized but we have left it as a loop for easier comparison to the code in the question.

```
ELO1 <- c(1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 
                              1500.000, 1500.000, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1475.898, 1500.000, 1475.000, 1486.617, 1512.516)
ELO2 <- c(1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1500.000, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1487.500, 1487.500, 1512.500, 1499.550, 1500.450, 1499.550, 1512.950, 1487.050, 1512.950, 1524.102, 1500.000)
HomeWinner <- c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)
n <- length(HomeWinner)   

lloss <- function(K) {
  P1ExpWin <- 1/(1 + 10^((ELO2 - ELO1)/400))
  P2ExpWin <- 1 - P1ExpWin
  for (r in 1:n) {
    if (HomeWinner[r] == 1) {
      ELO1[r] <- ELO1[r] + K * (1 - P1ExpWin[r])
      ELO2[r] <- ELO2[r] - K * P2ExpWin[r]
    }
    else{
      ELO1[r] <- ELO1[r] - K * P1ExpWin[r]
      ELO2[r] <- ELO2[r] + K * (1 - P2ExpWin[r])
    }
  }

  P1ExpWin <- 1/(1 + 10^((ELO2 - ELO1)/400))
  P2ExpWin <- 1 - P1ExpWin
  LogError <- HomeWinner * log(P1ExpWin) + (1-HomeWinner) * log(P1ExpWin)
  -mean(LogError) # LogLossELO
}

rng <- c(0, 100)
opt <- optimize(lloss, rng); opt
## $minimum
## [1] 76.05614
##
## $objective
## [1] 0.6833352
```

Below we plot the result.

```
curve(Vectorize(lloss)(K), rng[1], rng[2], xname = "K", ylab = "LogLossELO")
with(opt, abline(h = objective, v = minimum))
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Yes!
After some adjustment to my original work, that is exactly what I needed!
Thank you very much! I learned so much from this example!